# Possible to dereference this pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

I have

```
void *ptr = malloc(9);
printf("%X", ptr); //this shows the value of memory pointed to by ptr

//I want to try to see what ever is at the memory location by dereferenced ptr
printf("%c", (*ptr)); // try to dereference the pointer
```

this however causes a compiler error... how can I see the value pointed to be the memory allocated in ptr, I know it'll be some garbage value, I just want to see

Comment: It might not be some garbage value. It might blow up your computer if you're particularly unlucky.

Comment: Your first comment is wrong: You don't print the value pointed to by ptr, but are trying to print the value of ptr itself. Also, you must use format `"%p"` for pointers, or you get UB.

Comment: what does UB stand for??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void *ptr = malloc(9);
printf("%X", ptr); //this shows the value of memory pointed to by ptr
```

The previous line shoud have been:

```
printf("%p", ptr); //this shows the value of ptr
```

`"%X"` is for `int`, using it for pointers invokes UB, meaning anything can happen.

```
//I want to try to see what ever is at the memory location by dereferenced ptr
printf("%c", (*ptr)); // try to dereference the pointer
```

Because `void`is an incomplete type, it cannot be dereferenced. Cast to a pointer of the desired type first, then we can talk. For `char` that line would be:

```
printf("%c", *(char*)ptr); // try to dereference the pointer
```

But if you try to use a value before assigning it, beware of trap representations and other fun stuff.

Some more tips for you:

- Always compile with all warnings enabled. Add options `"-Wall -Wextra -pedantic"`
- Decide on C or C++. This example works same for both though.
- Get the standard, or at least the last working draft. Wikipedia has pointers to them.
- If you post a question here, try to include a short, concise example, which can be compiled immediately. This time it was good anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be dereferenced because you have declared it as `void` and `void` has no size.  You can dereference it if you cast it to something which has a size, though.  For example, `printf("%c", *(char *)ptr);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this `printf("%c\n", *((char*)ptr));`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has now idea what kind of data to look for when it dereferences ptr. You can do a typecast to char*. `printf("%c", *((char*)ptr));`

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can surely do this in practice, but it is **undefined behavior**:

For C, E.g. in ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, WG14/N1256
Annex J.2.1

```
The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
...
The value of the object allocated by the malloc function is used (7.20.3.3).
...
```